# Why value is destroyed?

Tags: perl

I looking for field name where `search` text is found

```
my $field;
for $field ( qw' email phone name ' ) {
    last   if $user->$field =~ /$search/;
}
print $field; # undef
```

Here if `$user->email` matched then the `last` command is called.
Thus I expect `$field` should have `email` as value. But it is actually `undef`

Why value of `$field` variable after the loop is `undef`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The loop var is scoped to the loop.

Use

```
my ($field) = grep { $user->$_ =~ /\Q$search/ } qw( email phone name );
```

or

```
use List::Util qw( first );

my $field = first { $user->$_ =~ /\Q$search/ } qw( email phone name );
```

Comment: If you want to add it to your answer, [perlsyn](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops) says "The foreach loop iterates over a normal list value and sets the scalar variable VAR to be each element of the list in turn. If the variable is preceded with the keyword my, then it is lexically scoped, and is therefore visible only within the loop. Otherwise, the variable is implicitly local to the loop and regains its former value upon exiting the loop."

Comment: @Dada: hm. Where this localization is handy?

Comment: @EugenKonkov: As the for loop aliases the elements it iterates over, keeping the last value might cause weird changes at a distance.

Comment: @Eugen Konkov, It would have been super useful before lexical vars were introduced. Now, we use `for my $x ()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not working since the "$field" is in global scope it is implicitly localised in the for loop since the same variable is used there as well. If your requirement is just to print or get the matched value in a variable then your code should be similar to :

```
#This variable will have the field name
my $result;

foreach my $field ( qw ' email phone name ' ) {
    if ($user->{$field} =~ /$search/) {
        $result = $field;
        last;
    }
}

print $result;
```

or, grep can be used to filter values from an array. [Filtering values using Perl grep](https://perlmaven.com/filtering-values-with-perl-grep)

P.S. updated my answer after @Eugen's comment.

Comment: no, `$field` is in scope of file, but it is implicitly localized to the loop too. Like `local $field`. See @Dada comment above

Answer (score 0):

You will get more detail understanding from below example.

```
  1 #!/usr/bin/perl
  2
  3 my $field;
  4 my $user  = {
  5     'email' => 'my@email.com'
  6 };
  7
  8 foreach my $search ( "email" , "phone", "name" ) {
  9     if ($user->{$search} ){
 10         $field = $user->{$search};
 11         last;
 12     }
 13 }
 14 print "\n===field========$field====\n";
```